# Deleting a cloned node erases all paragraphs

Tags: 8, entities

Suppose node A contains a paragraphs field with a paragraph entity X. Duplicating the node by means of [Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) will create a new node - let's call it node B - with an exact copy of paragraph X. It is even possible to change the contents of X in node A and B independently. 
But when A or B is deleted, X will be erased from *both* nodes. Obviously this is because there has never been created a new entity when replicating the paragraph, but only a new entity revision.

For Drupal 7, this behavior is documented in [Paragraphs data loss with Node clone module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2394313) and at least partly fixed by a patch.
But none of this seems to be the case for the Drupal 8 dev version of Node clone. Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this issue?

Drupal 8.2.0

Paragraph 8.x-1.0+14-dev

Node clone 8.x-1.x-dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paragraph in 8.x integrates with the replicate project only at the moment: https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate

If you use that, cloning a node will also create clones of the used paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which prevents me from trying the impossible. - I also tried Replicate 8.x-1.x-dev, but I could not quickly find a way to implement it since there is no UI, and the API documentation is for D7 only. Did you manage to make it work in a comparable use case?

Comment: There's a https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate_ui project. It has a 8.x dev release that is now shown by default, no idea why. Use/try on your own risk :)

Comment: Indeed I thought there were no Drupal 8 Version of Replicate UI. But  thanks to your hint, I tried it now, and it seems to work like a charm. All paragraphs in a replicated node get a new entity id, so that there should be no more trouble with unintentionally deleted paragraphs.