# D8 - Paragraphs - Multilingual - Content Erasing

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

I'm running into an issue on my D8 site where Paragraphs (module) content is erasing from a replicated node when I change the language of the replicated node.

I am using Paragraphs 8.x-1.1, Replicate 8.x-1.x-dev, Replicate UI 8.x-1.x-dev, and Drupal core is a little behind at 8.2.3.

I understand there's some issues with Paragraphs and translating and I found that others seem to have this working, but I'm wondering if there's something small (hopefully) that I'm missing in order to get this working.

A similar thread to mine can be found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221692/deleting-a-cloned-node-erases-all-paragraphs) regarding deleting the cloned nodes.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was that I had the "Users may translate this field" checkbox checked for the paragraph field types in my content types. Once I unchecked those I was able to replicate the node, change the language, and the paragraph content did not erase.